# react native with push notification run in background

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement push notifications with react native with this plugin 
[react-native-push-notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).
what I succeed is to get notification when app is running(in foreground), but what I'm looking to do is to get notification when app is closed(background), not running and when I get notification to go into the app.

my code

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.initEventPushNotification()
    this.initPushNotification()

}


initEventPushNotification() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', (state) => {
        console.log(state)
        if (state === 'background') {
            PushNotification.popInitialNotification((notification) => {
                if (notification) {
                    this.onNotification(notification);
                }
            });
            PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
        }
        if (state === 'active') {
            PushNotification.popInitialNotification((notification) => {
                if (notification) {
                    this.onNotification(notification);
                }
            })
        }


    });

}



initPushNotification() {
    console.log('init')
    PushNotification.configure({

        // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
        onRegister: function (token) {
            AppStore.setFCMToken(token.token)
            FirebaseService.setTokenData(token.token)
        },

        // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
        onNotification: function (notification) {
            if (!notification.userInteraction) {
                PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
            }
            if (notification) {
                console.log(notification)
                PushNotification.localNotification({
                    /* Android Only Properties */
                    id: '0', // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
                    ticker: "My Notification Ticker", // (optional)
                    autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
                    largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
                    smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
                    bigText: "My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded", // (optional) default: "message" prop
                    subText: "This is a subText", // (optional) default: none
                    color: "red", // (optional) default: system default
                    vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
                    vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
                    tag: 'some_tag', // (optional) add tag to message
                    group: "group", // (optional) add group to message
                    ongoing: false, // (optional) set whether this is an "ongoing" notification

                    /* iOS only properties */

                    message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
                    playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
                    soundName: 'default', // (optional) Sound to play when the notification is shown. Value of 'default' plays the default sound. It can be set to a custom sound such as 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)
                    number: '10', // (optional) Valid 32 bit integer specified as string. default: none (Cannot be zero)
                    repeatType: 'day', // (Android only) Repeating interval. Could be one of `week`, `day`, `hour`, `minute, `time`. If specified as time, it should be accompanied by one more parameter 'repeatTime` which should the number of milliseconds between each interval
                    actions: '["Yes", "No"]',  // (Android only) See the doc for notification actions to know more
                });
            }
            // process the notification

            // required on iOS only (see fetchCompletionHandler docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html)
            // notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
        },

        // ANDROID ONLY: GCM Sender ID (optional - not required for local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications)
        senderID: "XXXXXXXXXX1", // my sender ID

        // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
        },

        // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
        // default: true
        popInitialNotification: true,

        /**
          * (optional) default: true
          * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
          * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
          */
        requestPermissions: true,
    });


}
```

I'm using firebase function to send the notification

```
export const sendNotificationTest = functions.https
.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { token } = req.body;
        let tokens = "coeC4T6tmeU:APA91bGEQs4MRQXq4C09SKpyK2Oxz7gIKS-QdoGGKeCcxQj2CXGpCD7qe763WnFVgQRer81iZGscASVq-QP7_I81xtCM9vfiPitQJ4P6HFSH3QiGQQljiLPBixsVcCtbDNCZX4z4u8n-"
        let payload = {
            data: {
                body: 'Message body',
                title: 'Message title',
                color: "#00ACD4",
                priority: "high",
                icon: "ic_notif",
                show_in_foreground: 'true',
                channelId:'sqtrivia-channel'

            },
            notification: {
                title: "Alarm",
                subtitle: "First Alarm",
                body: "First Alarm",
                click_action: "com.myapp.MyCategory" // The id of notification category which you defined with FCM.setNotificationCategories
            }
        };
        let options = { priority: "high", contentAvailable: true };
        // Set the message as high priority and have it expire after 24 hours.



        console.log('token', token)
        if(token){
            let d = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload, options);
            return res.status(200).send({ success: d })
        }
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'you should send token' })


    } catch (e) {
        console.info(e)
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 0 })

    }
})
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.moonsite.sqlivetrivia">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
      <!-- <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </service>
      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </service> -->
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

        <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
          <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
              <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
              </receiver>
          <!-- <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/> -->
        <!-- <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" /> -->
          <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        </application>

</manifest>
```

as I said before, I succeed to get notification only when app is running when I send with firebase http function.I tested only in android for now.

when I send in background I get success response when I test in postman

```
{
"success": {
    "results": [
        {
            "messageId": "0:1526575831372268%a0cec506f9fd7ecd"
        }
    ],
    "canonicalRegistrationTokenCount": 0,
    "failureCount": 0,
    "successCount": 1,
    "multicastId": 8639210245128054000
}
```

}

but I don't get it in device(in background)

Comment: Does it work if you manually send a notification form Firebase dashboard?

Comment: @CristianTr I tested in firebase dashboard, it works also just when app is open.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as if you are sending a cloud message that has both a `notification` and `data` payload. In order for Android apps to wake-up upon receipt of a message while the app is in the background, then you may only send a message with a `data` payload.

Have a look at these docs--in particular the part about **"Silent remote push notifications"**:
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/trouble-shooting.md

and FCM docs for more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: if I want to recive when app in background, so I need to send only payload with data like it?  let payload = {
                data: {
                    body: 'Message body',
                    title: 'Message title',
                    color: "#00ACD4",
                    priority: "high",
                    icon: "ic_notif",
                    show_in_foreground: 'true',
                    channelId:'xxxxx-channel'

                },

Comment: @AdirZoari :: Correct. Android will only wake apps if the message contains only a `data` payload. iOS is different. iOS can contain both--for that case generally send the appropriate payload to the respective device.

Comment: I changed it to what you say. but I still get only when app in background. I get success in response but not get in when app in background.

Comment: @AdirZoari :: please take a look at the "Trouble Shooting" section called "About Notifications.." in this link :: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/trouble-shooting.md

Answer (score 1):

From FCM docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Background Restricted Apps (Android P or newer)

Starting Jan 2019, FCM will not deliver messages to apps which were put into background restriction by the user (such as via: Setting -> Apps and Notification -> [appname] -> Battery). Once your app is removed from background restriction, new messages to the app will be delivered as before.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a Background message handler?

If not then try this:

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
   console.log('Your message was handled in background');
});
```

Comment: When app cleared from background, `setBackgroundMessageHandler` is not called. Do you face this issue?